# RestSharp "Invalid JSON string" when connection lost

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

Is there a way to see when RestClient.ExecuteAsync() fails because of a lost connection?

When I cut off the network connection, the response contains a SerializationException "Invalid JSON String", as if it received content that could not be parsed. I would instead expect an exception related to the network connection, like some sort of IOException for example.

For now I might assume that if ContentLength==0 then the response wasn't actually a response but rather a lack of connection, so that I can report the appropriate error to the user and suggest they check their Internet connection.

Comment: do you have try catch block? that helps in this type of situation

Comment: Yes, I do have a try/catch. ExecuteAsync() doesn't actually throw an exception in this case; what I mean by "fails" is that it calls your callback with a Response object which contains an ErrorException property, which is where the SerializationException is stored.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that when you cut off the network connection, a different network connection is used that goes through an HTTP proxy.  Local ISPs often will serve up "did you mean" HTML pages in response to failed address lookups.

Some example scenarios: if you're testing on a mobile device over wifi to a server on the local network and then you shut off wifi, the connection might instead be attempted over cellular data.

Or, you're testing over VPN and the VPN connection goes down, causing the device to fall back to a local wifi network.

If your client is on a Windows machine, try making the connection through a tool such as Fiddler to see what kind of response is actually coming back.  Or use Wireshark.  Chances are good that the response is something from a "helpful" proxy server.